# Adjective for attractiveness of a sidewalk with regards to the movement of people through it?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

So I'm looking for a specific adjective that indicates that the flow of people through a street/sidewalk- the path that people would have to walk being appealing. Specifically when there are desired locations nearby and it is not cumbersome and the human traffic? through that place is appealing. i.e. how you would move through the sidewalk is appealing.

For example, if there's a street and on that street, there's a hairdresser next to a bakery next to the mall, and you say to yourself that it's very convenient and that it's easy to move from one place to the next, you would say

> 'Oh! This street is very ____'

or

> 'The **line of flow** is beautiful' (with a replacement for "line of flow")

Either a noun for the phenomenon or an adjective describing the street's easy accessibility to all the shops with emphasis on the person's experience moving through it (something flow-y) is what I'm looking for. A street being accessible, scenic or efficient is nice, but one with 'flow'

I'm trying to look for a single adjective or even if it is a professional term it would be appreciated.
Many thanks for the help. Please refrain from using long-winded phrases as potential solutions or that would do the job, I'm looking to see if there is a real solution otherwise I'm better off without...
(unless the phrase is succinct)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79827/discussion-on-question-by-esu-adjective-for-attractiveness-of-a-sidewalk-with-re).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think what you want to say is:

> The ***streetlife*** or ***street-scene*** here is great.

I'm having a little difficulty locating a good reference for definitions, but these terms are commonly used.

For example one answer to this [Quora question](https://www.quora.com/What-cities-in-the-world-have-the-best-street-life) describes the *dong-son* I think you may be looking for:

> Q: What cities in the world have the best street life?
>
> A: New Orleans, because of all of the street artists & performers. Also, in the French Quarter, you can walk up to a bar, grab a drink, & walk down the street with it. Cafe Du Monde, in front of which a lot of street performers and artists set up, is open-air, for the most part, so you can sit at a table w/your coffee & beignets & catch a "free" show. I highly recommend tipping the performers, though.

Comment: To me that seems more about the people on the street providing lively entertainment, rather than the aesthetics of the way pedestrians walk through the space defined by the street. (I may be overthinking it).

Comment: yeah it's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a word I didn't know existed and I'm still going to keep my eyes out for future answers :D

Comment: @AE - I think *streetlife* is definitely people-focused. I think street scene encompasses the atmosphere from the street, the shops, and the people.  The way I’m understanding the OP, if there was no pedestrian traffic there’d be no *dong-son* even if the street looked inviting.

Comment: "streetscape" as an alternative to these, that centers layout and view over people

Comment: Why are these answers being downvoted? One does the best one can with what one has. Even the OP is not sure of what he is looking for. Others should have a little forbearance.

Comment: @Lambie - Agree.  I’ll +1 your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In English, you can say: a sidewalk is attractive to walk down. There are many ways to describe whether walking down a particular sidewalk is fun, exciting, visually stimulating, etc.

In urban planning, there is a term for people walking on sidewalks: 
sidewalk traffic

For architecture, there is a term for how people move around a building: circulation in a building.

The sidewalks [on X street or avenue] is an attractive pathway through the downtown area.

The sidewalks attract pedestrians. They are pedestrian-attracting sidewalks.

**An attractive or appealing mix of businesses line the sidewalks of downtown streets**.

We say shops line the sidewalks.

The flow of pedestrian traffic see the mix of businesses that line the sidewalks of downtown streets.

[circulation in a building](https://www.google.com/search?ei=xUMxW6jxF8G85gKnv6fABA&q=architecture%20%2B%20%22circulation%20in%20a%20building%22%20%20-movie%20-film&oq=architecture%20%2B%20%22circulation%20in%20a%20building%22%20%20-movie%20-film&gs_l=psy-ab.3...54033.69179.0.69454.42.40.2.0.0.0.171.3796.24j13.37.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..8.0.0....0.-vJFOup0Mk4)

[sidewalk traffic](https://www.planning.org/pas/reports/report95.htm)